# ViewDragHelper animation listener

Tags: android, android-animation, viewdraghelper

I'm using ViewDragHelper to slide a view to a new location, and I'm trying to use `viewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(dragView, x, y)`. The question is: How do I get a notification after the slide animation is complete? I'm looking for a way to listen to the slide animation events (especially something like onSlideAnimationComplete() ). Any idea folks?

```
private boolean smoothSlideTo(float slideOffset) {
    final int topBound = getPaddingTop();
    int x = (int) (slideOffset * (getWidth() - transformer.getMinWidthPlusMarginRight()));
    int y = (int) (topBound + slideOffset * getVerticalDragRange());
    if (viewDragHelper.smoothSlideViewTo(dragView, x, y)) {
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: see [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/b747e89c1e1a1e314ca6)

Comment: @pskink can you be more specific how is your code related to my question? I still don't know where to capture the animation complete event.

Comment: first read the docs, then see how i implemented animation support in my code, running my code would be helpful too

Comment: do you know now how it works?

Comment: @pskink No I don't, you are not answering my question

Comment: i gave you not only idea but also the working code, did you read `viewDragHelper#smoothSlideViewTo` docs as i suggested?

Comment: man, i appreciate your help, but i don't think you understood my question correctly

Comment: then pardon me, where do you put "onSlideAnimationComplete()"

Answer (score 0):

It seems viewdraghelper doesn't have listener or callback when doing animation, but you can solve it by implement onViewDragStateChanged and judge through its state, like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewDragStateChanged(int state) {
        if (state == 0) {
            if (settleDestX == contentView.getLeft() && swipeOverListener != null) {
                swipeOverListener.onSwipeOver(settlePosition);
            }
        }
    }
```

state==1 implies dragging, state==2 implies scrolling, state==0 implies idle.